# Program/script for - Multiple Testing of Local Maxima for Detection of Peaks

Tags: maxima

I am analyzing genomic data am looking for a way quickly to parse out significant peaks from noise for a range of statistical (e.g. Tajima's D) measures across chromosomes.

Does anyone know of a script that implements the peak detection protocol described in Garvilov and Adler (2011) Multiple tests of local maxima for detection of peaks in 1D. Ann Stat 39(6) 3290-3319, doi: 10.1214/1111-AOS943

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with a similar problem myself.  I'm not familiar with the paper you cite, but I think the GWAS literature traditionally defines "significant" with respect to a null distribution under neutral expectation as generated via permutation, bootstrapping and recalculation of the data.  I'm sorry to "ask for clarification" but could you tell me a little more about your approach and rationale?